# How to send to Activity Apps Permission Monitor Android

Tags: android, permissions, sdk, camera, monitor

I'm developing with Android SDK (JAVA).

I have a background service who takes info about the system, camera, battery, and it fires notifications because the camera is opening in background to get the resolution. I want to inform this in my app to show a confirm alert to redirect to this activity: [image]

How can I launch this?
Thanks